# I can not use ubuntu with the gdm disabled

Tags: gdm

Hello everybody this is my first post here I'm new to linux.
Here's my problem when I disable the gdm (with this command`sudo systemctl stop gdm`) to have only a console interface, my screen goes totally black and I can't do anything.
Then I need to restart my computer.
Can someone help me

Comment: I don't fully understand, if you have only `gdm3` installed (as a DM), then your system will be text only (ie. no GUI) if it's stopped. Stopping `gdm3` should stop GUI functionality yes; but you should still be able to login & use the machine as a server/text based system (even starting some X or GUI functions from the terminal). You've not provided an OS or release (`gdm3` is the current DM used by GNOME)

Comment: Yes I'm running on ubuntu LT20.04 but I know it is meaned to do that but in my case I can't do this in case this what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

Stopping gdm does not free the tty that GDM is using.

Instead, ignore GDM and switch TTYs.

- CTRL+ALT+F3 (or F4) to reach a tty login.
- CTRL+ALT+F1 to return to GDM.

Comment: thank you but what if I want to disable it by default (I tried with this (sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target)) when I got lucky it will show me the console interface but it will in 90% of the case do a black screen